# CVS in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, cvs

I'm an eclipse user, and I'm using IDEA now, but in the cvs, I don't know how to config, there's a CVS root setting, which should I use, to the project folder or just to the /home/cvsroot, if is set to /home/cvsroot how to config the module to get link from the repository, and is there any way to see the file version as eclipse can see in IDEA?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I used CVS, but for most other VCSs, you put the Project directory as the VCS root. I believe for CVS, you also have to set the CVS Root from the VCS menu.

Have a read through the CVS section of IntelliJ's [manual](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/cvs-reference.html).